# JQuery parse json for multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var tdValue = $.parseJSON(getMedicationOrderInstance(freqKey, $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', dateFrom), $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', dateTo)));
```

this is my ajax call which is returning following json and I am trying to parse but throwing exception

> Exception thrown and not caught json2.js (503,13)

```
 {
      "25": [
        "00:00",
        "05:00",
        "10:00",
        "15:00",
        "20:00"
      ],
      "26": [
        "01:00",
        "06:00",
        "11:00",
        "16:00",
        "21:00"
      ],
      "27": [
        "02:00",
        "07:00",
        "12:00",
        "17:00",
        "22:00"
      ]
    }
```

Guys please help. It's cracking my head.

```
function getMedicationOrderInstance(key, dateFrom, dateTo) {
    return $.when(
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    cls: ".....MedicationSearchController",
                    mtd: "getFreqDates",
                    ses: SessID,
                    frequencyKey: key,
                    startDate: dateFrom,
                    endDate:dateTo

                }

            })
    ).then(function(data){
        if (data && data.success === true) {

            return data.results;
        } else {
            // alert(data.exception);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `getMedicationOrderInstance` seems `async` to me..

Comment: your json seems valid

Comment: @Rayon getMedicationOrderInstance() is a function for ajax call.

Comment: @ray — Well in that case, play with the `callback` or `promise`

Comment: `var tdValue = {}; getMedicationOrderInstance(freqKey, $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', dateFrom), $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', dateTo)).then(function(data){ tdValue  = $.parseJSON(data)});`

Comment: parseJSON is obsolete and the new version json2 doesn't even use it anymore. it has been replaced by JSON.parse

Comment: Also, in my experience you rarely need to use parseJSON anyway. If you define the `dataType` as json `$.ajax` will do the parsing for you.

Comment: @smoksnes your way is not showing any error now but I am getting {} empty response although from backend I have checked, it's returning json.

Comment: @ray, can you share the code for `getMedicationOrderInstance`?

Comment: @smoksnes shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use `$.parseJSON`. [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will do it for you, as long as you set `dataType: 'json'`.

> If `json` is specified, the response is parsed using `jQuery.parseJSON`
>   before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed
>   JSON object is made available through the `responseJSON` property of the
>   `jqXHR` object.

You should be able to keep `$.when` in `getMedicationOrderInstance`, but here I simplify it a little bit, and return the *original* `jqXHR` object. And let the consumer decide what to do with it.

```
function getMedicationOrderInstance(key, dateFrom, dateTo) {
    // Return the jqXHR here...
    return $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    cls: ".....MedicationSearchController",
                    mtd: "getFreqDates",
                    ses: SessID,
                    frequencyKey: key,
                    startDate: dateFrom,
                    endDate:dateTo

                }
            });
}
```

Then you can do like this:

```
var tdValue = {};
// I moved these to separate variables to increase readability only...
var parsedDateFrom = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', dateFrom);
var parsedDateTo = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', dateTo);

var defObj = getMedicationOrderInstance(freqKey, parsedDateFrom, parsedDateTo);

// When the call is complete do this.
defObj.then(function(data){
    // If you properly set dataType in the ajax-call you don't need to parse json.
    console.log(data.result);
    tdValue = data.result;

    // or possibly...
    // tdValue = data; 

    alert('done');
});
```